# Disable minification in Grunt (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I recently started using GruntJS through Yeoman and I like the idea of Javascript minification, but it presents difficulties during development. I tried to disable uglify,usemin, etc in different combinations in the Gruntfile but everything seems to be dependent on another thing and breaks the process. Is there a simple way to disable minification? I am using the latest versionof Grunt offered by Yeoman to date, I found that older solutions have a different Gruntfile setup than that usd with Yeoman.

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  options: {
    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
  },
  html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
},
```

http://hastebin.com/gicabukojo.js

Comment: You can change the [configuration of grunt-contrib-minify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/README.md) to do what you want, and keep the task enabled. I don't know yeoman, but there's still a Gruntfile.js, right?

Comment: yes there is still a gruntfile but i see this in comments for uglify ` //By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.// uglify: {...` see added gruntfile

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvote, please comment if you feel I didn't describe the question properly

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the grunt file in your question - the question should be self contained.

Comment: I included the link to the entire Gruntfile because I have absolutely no clue about which part of the Gruntfile is required to disable minificaition. I am surprised at the downvotes because I would imagine disabling minification during development would be a common requirement, I just can't figure out how. I imagine it occurs somewhere within the Gruntfile so that's why I included the link to the entire file.
If this isn't a stackoverflow type question please say why before my next downvote so I can fix this please :-/

Comment: Read Ryley's comment to see why you were downvoted. Has nothing to do with what you're asking--it's how you're asking it. Also, I looked at the gruntfile you posted. Why can't you just remove the `<!-- Usemin block -->` comments in your HTML file?

Comment: @Jonathan maybe I got all that flak because the answer to the question was so simple... IT WORKS for grunt serve. You could not have known what my problem was unless I posted the entire Gruntfile for you to peruse contrary to popular belief. However removing the uglify from the grunt build config still causes errors. it's writing HTML from my index.html file into the top my main.js file. I can still manage with just grunt serve so If you post your comment as an answer I will assign you the bounty. A vote up and accepted answer

Comment: @fazras to make this more useful to others coming across to this page, could you possibly update your question with the relevant parts of your gruntfile? I'll mention it in the answer when I post it.

Comment: I don't have any Usemin block... but still somehow the scaffolding seems to be minifying my js...

Comment: ah.. `<!-- build:` lines are the so-called `<!-- Usemin block -->`s -- I still want the concatenation, I just want to turn off the uglyfing/minifying for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment block was in your Gruntfile:

```
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
// of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
// wish to use the Usemin blocks.
```

Based on this, removing the `<!-- Usemin block -->` from your index.html file should prevent the `useminPrepare` grunt task from minifying your javascript.

Additionally, you can edit your `uglify` task to create new files to not overwrite your dev files by adding `.min` to the file extension:

```
 uglify: {
   dist: {
     files: {
       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.min.js'
       ]
     }
   }
 },
```

Comment: But what to do when there's no <!-- Usemin block --> tag present in your index.html?

Comment: @SebastianHernandez the so-called `<!-- Usemin block -->`s are the lines that start `<!-- build:js` or `<!-- build:css` in `app/index.html`; see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blocks

Answer (score 2):

I needed to tweak the usemin `flow:` option:

as per [yeoman grunt usemin's fine manual](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#flow), the default `flow:` is

```
{ steps: { js: ['concat', 'uglify'], css: ['concat', 'cssmin'] }, post: {} }
```

Here is a [gist of how I modified](https://gist.github.com/tingletech/945deccb63ea9d25fd4aff16c137abe3) my yo webapp `Gruntfile.js` to remove `uglify` from the flow.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!