# angular-fullstack turn off minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am trying to get started with the yeoman generator Angular-Fullstack. I am using TypeScript, but when I compile and run all the js files get put into one large app.js. This would be fine for production, but for debugging its a hassle. Does anyone know how to change this so just the compiles JS shows and gets executed?

EDIT

I am using the default gulp.babel.js file for all of the configurations. There is no grunt file, so alas those links are to a different issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable minification in Grunt (Yeoman)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724629/disable-minification-in-grunt-yeoman)

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724629/disable-minification-in-grunt-yeoman

Comment: I should have said in my question, but I am not using Grunt, but gulp. There is no grunt file, just a gulp.babel.js file.

Comment: For gulp, this may help https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/443